# CSS dynamic font size and position border text

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hi is there a way to dynamically resize the font style and the position of the font

[image]

so that when the image is resize to any viewport the design and the ratio of the image and the font stays the same?

Answer (score 1):

yes,there is.

```
  <your div>{
      font-size : 2vw;
    }
    img{
      height : 10vh;
      width : 12vw;
    }
```

here vw means viewport-width and vh means viewport-height that expands or shrinks when u resize window.The font size will keep constant ratio with your image-width.

Comment: did you also consider the position and rotation of the text? when resizing it wont retain its position

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use CSS units' [relative lengths](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_units.asp).

Example:

```
<div style="font-size: 3vw;">
  This text size is according to the device screen width and this is done by CSS
</div>
```

Comment: i see but when resized the text does not retain its position

Comment: You can also use relative lengths for that e.g. `top: 10%; left: 10%;`